# jekyll with large files -- avoid copying

Tags: jekyll, symlink

I have an image gallery built for my blog engined by Jekyll, the directory is `/assets/galleries`. Everytime I run `jekyll build`, it takes so long to copy all these images to the `_site` directory. I was wondering if there is some way to make the building process faster?

Here is the solutions I got right now.

- separate the image gallery from the blog. I created a repo called `Gallery` and used project page, then link the page to my blog. But I really hate the idea to have to separate things apart.
- as proposed in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972137/how-can-i-setup-jekyll-for-a-blog-with-a-large-image-directory-so-as-to-avoid-d), symlink. I don't know if I did it wrong, I just couldn't get the result I want. Here is what I tried: `ln -s assets/_galleries _site/assets/_galleries` (I add the underscore to avoid copying)

Any ideas or insights are appreciated. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with rsync. I did a blog post about [speeding up jekyll generation with rsync](http://tuananh.org/2014/07/26/speed-up-jekyll-site-generation-with-rsync/) the other day.

- tell jekyll not to use that folder by rename the folder with understore `_` in front. (SOURCE)
- tell jekyll not to touch that folder when regen (GENERATED) in config file
- rsync those 2 folders